# php checking if null with @if inside @foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, database, foreach, laravel-blade

I'm tring to check if `null` with `@if` for data in `show.blade`

```
<li id="step6"><strong>Schritt 6<br>@foreach($dbQuery as $query){{$query->sixth_step}}@endforeach</strong></li>
```

if `sixth_step` is null to remove the `<li> list item element`

tried the following but not working

```
@foreach($dbQuery as $query){{$query->sixth_step}}
if({{$query->sixth_step}} !=null)
<li id="step6"><strong>Schritt 6<br>@foreach($dbQuery as $query){{$query->sixth_step}}@endforeach</strong></li>
endif
@endforeach
```

`dd($query->sixth_step);` gives `null`

Also tried `@if(isset` `@if(empty` didn't work
What is the best way to hide the `<li>` element when sixth_step is null?

Comment: `@if($query->sixth_step)...@endif` should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you provided is the real code,

1. You don't have to add `{{ }}` inside the `if` statement. You can rewrite it like `@if($query->sixth_step)`
2. You need to add `@` before the `if`
3. You don't have to query again inside the `<li>`

Or provide the exact error what you are getting.

Please check the refactored code below

```
@foreach($dbQuery as $query)
    {{$query->sixth_step ?? ''}} <!-- if you intent to print 'sixth step' -->
    @if($query->sixth_step)
        <li id="step6">
            <strong>Schritt 6<br>
                {{$query->sixth_step}}
            </strong>
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`is_null()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) to specifically target only for `null` values because other methods consider false, [], 0, null all as same.

```
@foreach($dbQuery as $query)
    @if(!is_null($query->sixth_step))
        /* your HTML */
    @else
        {{$query->sixth_step}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```